# Invoke javascript callback repeatedly from C++ module in node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, node-modules, node.js-addon

So I am writing a node.js module in C++ which processes data from a camera. I want to invoke a callback function in my `app.js` file whenever new data is available.

**What I have at the moment**

Right now I have in my node javascript file (`app.js`) the following code. Every second it calls a function in my C++-Module and returns the number of frames that have been processed so far:

```
setInterval(function () {
        var counter = MyCPPModule.NumberOfFrames();
        console.log(counter);
    }, 1000);
```

In my C++ file I have the following functions.

**1.)** I have a function to get the number of frames - the function that gets called from javascript as above- , where `frameCounter` refers to a global variable.

```
void NumberOfFrames(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Local<Integer> retval = v8::Integer::New(isolate, frameCounter);
    args.GetReturnValue().Set(retval);
}
```

**2.)** And I have a C++-callback function in the C++ module that gets triggered whenever a new frame is available (just to be clear, this callback is independent of node.js and has nothing directly to do with node.js-callbacks).

```
void NewFrameAvailable(char** imageBuffer, /* more arguments */)
{
// ... 
     frameCounter++;  // increment global variable
// ...
}
```

All of this works fine.

**What I would like to accomplish**

Instead of registering a function with `setInterval` in my javascript code. I would like to somehow register a function with my C++ module that gets called repeatedly whenever a new frame is available from the camera. It should behave like `setInterval`, but instead of being triggered every second, it gets triggered when a frame is available.

The code that I am hoping for on the javascript-side would be something like:

```
MyCPPModule.setMyFrameInterval(function (msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });
```

Inside the C++ Module I would like to do something like:

```
void NewFrameAvailable(char** imageBuffer, /* more arguments */)
{ 
    // ... 
    frameCounter++;  // increment global variable
    Local<Function> cb = /* WHAT DO I DO HERE*/ ;
    Isolate*isolate = /* WHAT DO I DO HERE */;
    const unsigned argc = 1;
    Local<Value> argv[argc] = { String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, std::to_string(frameCounter)) };
    cb->Call(Null(isolate), argc, argv);
    // ...
}
```

and a function that registers the javascipt-callback with `setMyFrameInterval`:

```
void setMyFrameInterval(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Local<Function> cb = Local<Function>::Cast(args[0]); // make this somehow global? 
    Isolate*isolate = args.GetIsolate()
    //...
}
```

So, how can I invoke the javascript callback from `NewFrameAvailable` (the C++ callback function which gets triggered when frames are available). I think I basically have to make the javascript function somehow globally available in the `setMyFrameInterval` function so that it is also known to the `newFrameAvailable` function. How do I do this?

Comment: I worked on a c++ project that used chromium embedded framework where I would write native C++ functions and bind them to global "window" object to call them from anywhere. Not sure if that helps. Just wanted to share.

Comment: @Sreekar: Thanks for the quick response. What is a global window object? I tried to make the javascript-function global inside the C++-Module, but I couldn't figure out how ...

Comment: I'm not aware of native programming with NodeJS. The global window object is the "window" object which represent browser window. (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp). If I want to call any JS function in the current JS context, I can call it using an inbuilt CEF function. All JS functions and objects were available to me using *V8Context* object.

Comment: @Sreekar: Ah, thanks very interesting! Yeah, I think I need something like that, but for node.

Comment: Checkout how the streaming methods (e.g. streamPNG, streamPDF) are implemented in [node-canvas](https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/blob/master/src/Canvas.cc#L449). [Nan::MakeCallback](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/node_misc.md#api_nan_make_callback) or [Nan::Call](https://github.com/nodejs/nan/blob/master/doc/maybe_types.md#api_nan_call) are probably of use to you.